# JavaScript: ImageClick through transparent iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a transperent iframe, which created by next JS function:

```
Frames.prototype.CreateIframe = function (frameName, frWidth, frHeight, zindex) {
    var frameObj = document.createElement('iframe');
    frameObj.width = PX(frWidth);
    frameObj.src = 'Content.htm';
    frameObj.height = PX(frHeight);
    frameObj.id = frameName;
    frameObj.name = frameName;
    frameObj.frameBorder = 0;
    frameObj.allowTransparency = 'allowtransparency';
    frameObj.style.zIndex = zindex;
    frameObj.style.position = 'absolute';
    frameObj.style.scrolling = 'no';
    frameObj.style.scroll = 'no';
    frameObj.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    frameObj.style.left = PX(0);
    frameObj.style.top = PX(0);
    GlobalClass.AppendChild(window, frameObj);
}
```

Below that is another iframe where the images are placed. I created event handlers for these images. For example `document.GetElementById("MyImage").onclick(alert("Click!"));`

If I run it by IE, everything works fine. But I run it by Chrome, Firefox, Opera nothing works. **How I can correct this?** 
The upper transparent iframe has event handlers and it works in IE also.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.GetElementById("MyImage").onclick= function(){
```

alert("Click!");
}